# How do I make ManyToManyField limit_choices_to equal to request.user (Django)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I should limit choices of manytomanyfield to logged in admin user profile, in django admin.

```
class News(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
   users=models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, limit_choices_to={"profile__school":      "request.user.profile.school"})
```

I have tried to implement it in admin.ModelAdmin, where I can access request.user, but couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: You don't. Django's user layer is request unaware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this in the model layer. Django's user layer is request unaware. Some code paths don't even have a request, for example if these are done through a Python script, or a Django management command.

You can limit the choices in the `ModelAdmin` by overriding `get_form`:

```
class NewsAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj=obj, change=change, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['users'].queryset = User.objects.filter(
            profile__school__profile__user=request.user
        )
        return form
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: It worked, but I had to replace "fields" with "base_fields"

Comment: @AlessandroCurseri: aarggghhhh... sorry, yes. Fixed.